# can i make a better ui for smb shares in my samsung tv

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio

this is my first question so I may have not put it right,
the thing is ... I have my pc and my samsung tv that is using tizen on the same network and I share media like movies and series to my tv through media streaming service my question here is can I make a better UI for that tv file browsing or even an app that take these media from my pc and put it in it in a good-looking GUI?